# How to parse <key name = "somename">value</key> into C# varaiables

Tags: c#, .net, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<settings>
    <key name="setting_name">true</key>
</settings>
```

this is the xml file i have (with multiple key value pairs), i need to get the value "true" in the C# variable "setting_name"

```
private static bool setting_name = true;
```

This is what i have done so far

```
var setting_name = doc.Descendants("key").Where(k => k.Attribute("name").Value. Equals("setting_name")).Select(e => e.Elements("key")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: `var setting_name = doc.Descendants("key").Where(k => k.Attribute("name").Value.
                    Equals("setting_name")).Select(e => e.Elements("key")).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: add your code to the question instead of comments

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I came up with a simple solution using "[Sanjid's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49378922/7434451)" and "[Phillip Ngan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49378705/7434451)" answer, which works really fine for my project with few key value pairs. hope this will help anyone seeing this post

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<settings>
    <key name="setting_name">true</key>
</settings>
```

Code to parse this .xml key value pair to bool

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("settings.xml"); //.xml file path

var setting_name = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//settings/key[@name=\"setting_name\"]");

bool setting_name = bool.Parse(setting_name[0].InnerText);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are wanting to parse out the "True", you can use this Linq 2 XML:

```
void Main()
{
    var doc = XDocument.Parse("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><settings><key name=\"setting_name\">true</key></settings>");
    string boolStr = doc.Root.Elements()
            .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "key" && e.Attribute("name").Value == "setting_name" )
            .Single().Value;
    bool value = bool.Parse(boolStr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to deserialize correctly to your class

```
public class Key
{
    [XmlText]
    public bool Value { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Setting { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("settings")]
public class Settings
{
    [XmlElement("key")]
    public List<Key> Keys { get; set; }

    public Settings()
    {
        Keys = new List<Key>();
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>    
                <settings>
                    <key name=""setting_name"">true</key>
                </settings>";

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
    Settings result;

    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        result = (Settings)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    var res = result.Keys.First();

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}", res.Setting, res.Value));
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I meant ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option can be to to use XPath. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx:

```
var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<settings>
  <key name = ""setting_name"">true</key>
</settings> ";

var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
var keys = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//settings/key[@name=\"setting_name\"]");
Console.WriteLine(keys[0].InnerText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with xml deserializer. It is better to use it that way. I am not sure about the performance, you will have to check that. But if tomorrow, there is something which is update in your xml, the serialization thing will be more maintainable is what I feel.

Use `System.Xml.Serialization` Namespace

Classes:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="key")]
    public class Key {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="settings")]
    public class Settings {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="key")]
        public Key Key { get; set; }
    }
```

And then something like this:

```
var path = "path to your xml";
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings[]));
var reader = new StreamReader(path);
reader.ReadToEnd();
var settings = (Settings[])serializer.Deserialize(reader);
reader.Close();
return settings;
```

Try and check if this works.
Note : I have not tested this code snippet. But you can try the idea

Answer (score -2):

In case you need to get more than 1 pair, I suggest to create dictionary and then perform search:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);

var dict = xDoc.Root.Elements("key").ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute("name").Value, x => x.Value);

var setting_name = dict.TryGetValue("setting_name", out var setting_name_str) 
    ? bool.TryParse(setting_name_str, out var setting_name_value) && setting_name_value
    : false; //default value or exception
```